# Codeblocks GCC being stubborn about compiling C

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, codeblocks

i am beginner in programing and i just installed codeblocks in my computer
when i want to run my codes it says it seems this progect has not been built yet and in terminal i put gcc --version but its not working and show this 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.then i put sudo apt install build-esstential but again: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. show this what should i do??

i want when i run my codes go in terminal and show me but its not working

Comment: `sudo apt install build-esstential` is something you'd use on Linux, but you seem to be on Windows. I think CodeBlocks installs GCC by default (an outdated one, but still). It doesn't work in the terminal because you didn't add it to the PATH. *"this progect has not been built yet"* Did you get any errors in the build log? How did you create the project and how are you compiling it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting suggests that you might be on Windows (which doesn't have the `sudo` command, since it's a Linux-specific command). In that case, you most likely have to install the compiler toolchain yourself, because Code::Blocks doesn't come with one bundled (since it can work with different compilers, and you need to choose which one do you want to use yourself).
Go to [MinGW's (Minimalist GNU for Windows) website](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) and download and install their compiler toolchain. Then you should be able to configure Code::Blocks to work with it (there should be a compiler auto-detection option somewhere in the menus).